# passing json as parameter in javascript with space in content

Tags: javascript, json

The following is working when the content is no space

```
<a onclick=fbShareDialog("{\"name\":\"aaaaaaa\"}">
```

but if there is a space between

```
<a onclick=fbShareDialog("{\"name\":\"bbbbb bbbbb\"}">
```

it throws   Uncaught SyntaxError:unexpected token illegal

as i think all the content is in quotation , why not works?

thanks in advance

Comment: That's because the space makes it seem like the end of the value of the `onclick` attribute, so your function call gets cut off midway through. To group it all into one value, put single quotes around the outside. `onclick='fbShareDialog("{\"name\":\"bbbbb bbbbb\"}")'`

Comment: Show where you are accessing json object

Comment: cookie monster's right, and you're also missing your closing parenthesis.

Comment: You're welcome. Curious though, what is going to be done with the JSON? If it's just going to get parsed, then you really don't need a JSON string at all since the JSON syntax will parse nicely into the JavaScript as object literal syntax if you remove the quotes outside the curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you escape the space and put everything within double quotes.

I can't test it out now but try something like.

Also, it may be a better idea if you didn't write this inline and wrote a function to catch the click event instead.

Comment: Escaping the space won't make a difference.

Comment: Just saw your comment. I got it now. Yarp.

Answer (score 0):

You're implying a quoteless-attribute, which is really bad form in HTML but unfortunately still allowed due to HTML's sordid history. The attribute is 'onclick', which actually includes fbShareDialog, but that isn't in quotes.

Try:

```
<a onclick='fbShareDialog({"name":"bbbbb bbbbb"})'>
```

Or better yet, bind your click events in a .js file for your app, not onclicks in the html.

Comment: it 's working  as  <a onclick='fbShare.......
but not works  for   <a onclick = "fbShare ....

Comment: Felix - thanks, forgot to clear out some leftover quotes from the copy. fixed.